# Cython `inline` methods not accessible

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

I am trying to use some `sklearn` modules that are written in Cython (which I do not speak).  In the module, a method is defined `cdef inline...`, and it seems that other `cdef` methods within the module use these methods, but I am unable to access them.

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/27972d429db0cce5f6dfb6206b868aa353d5e516/sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx#L404) is where the class is defined, and that there is a method `dist`:

```
cdef class EuclideanDistance(DistanceMetric):
    #STUFF

    cdef inline DTYPE_t dist(self, DTYPE_t* x1, DTYPE_t* x2,
                             ITYPE_t size) nogil except -1:
        return euclidean_dist(x1, x2, size)

    #MORESTUFF
```

And [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/27972d429db0cce5f6dfb6206b868aa353d5e516/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi#L1181) we see that the `dist` method is used elsewhere:

```
cdef inline DTYPE_t dist(self, DTYPE_t* x1, DTYPE_t* x2,
                         ITYPE_t size) nogil except -1:
    """Compute the distance between arrays x1 and x2"""
    self.n_calls += 1
    if self.euclidean:
        return euclidean_dist(x1, x2, size)
    else:
        return self.dist_metric.dist(x1, x2, size)   ####HERE!!!!
```

But when I try to use this method, it simply doesn't exist....

```
import sklearn.neighbors
help(sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.EuclideanDistance)
```

How do I access the `dist` method?

Comment: Items defined with `cdef` in `cython` are not accessible from Python.  https://notes-on-cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/function_declarations.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [DistanceMetric class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric). It is intended to be used like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('euclidean')

print(dist)
# <sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.EuclideanDistance at 0x7fabe405e848>
```

And then to access the dist method, use [`pairwise()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.pairwise), which will internally call the `dist()`

```
X = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

dist.pairwise(X)
# array([[0.        , 5.19615242],
#       [5.19615242, 0.        ]])
```

You can use also use two arrays X, Y and in the `pairwise()` method